# How to imitate apple's stock timer app's UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want my components to wrap around the wheel,
not allow a value of zero (across all components), and
display units statically in each component.

Basically the functionality of the minutes component in the UPickerView of the Timer in the Clock app on every iPhone.

ATM I want to know if it's possible to do the wrap around since I have had no luck finding examples online for multiple components.

Thanks in advance.